# Google Tag Manager tag is fired but event does not show up in Google Analytics Real Time Events Tab

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, web-analytics

I have created a tag which fires when the click url contains certain words. When I view the website in GTM debug mode the tag is getting fired. But the event is not getting captured on Google Analytics Real Time Events.

The following is the screenshot of my tag and trigger.

[image]

[image]

Will the real time events in Google Analytics not show until I publish the changes in GTM?

Comment: Do you by chance have a filter that removes your own visits from the report ? In any case you can easily check if the request is sent, by installing either the Chrome GA Debugger extension or the Google Tag Assistant, oder by simply looking at the network tab in your browsers developer tools (look for a call with a path that starts with "collect/" and has a "t" parameter (hit type) with the value of "event").

Comment: Thanks for the response. the tag does have the 't' parameter with value of  'event' when I check from the developer tools. My IP address is not filtered. So the request is being sent but not visible in real time. Should I wait for a few days to check if it shows up after data is processed? But I am not sure if it will because I am operating under GTM debug mode.

Comment: Tags in debug mode will still be fired (unless you checked the according checkbox in the tag settings, but then you would not see it in the network tab). GA will not dimiss calls from the debug mode. In realtime look in the "last 30 minutes" tab and if you can wait until tomorrow to see if the hits show up in the events report. If not report back and I'll try and think of something :-)

Comment: Hello Eike, the events are still not showing up in GA. I see that that the tags are firing and the data is being sent to GA. But it does not show up. I still havent published changes, doing all of this debug mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What the possible problems you may have(as you are saying your tag is firing and IP was not filtered in GA:

- Your tracking ID for GA is incorrect(or you are checking data in the wrong GA property): your tag config looks correct, so data should be sent to GA(as you are saying GTM trigger works fine);
- Trigger name is hidden, but looks like trigger type is "Click". Make sense to check if option "Wait for tags" was enabled. If this option is disabled and after click user redirecting on another website page, GTM may not have enough time after click and before redirection to send data to GA. And your tag will fire, but data will not be received to GA.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it was the tracking ID which was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It ended up being a double up in the GA id. I had used a constant variable to define the GA property but not removed the ID itself.

[image]